# 2 x 2 div - responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone please help me as I am getting really fed up with this.

I cant understand why the images in each col-xs-6 is overlapping and leaving white space on the sides.

I am trying to get all over the images of equal size and responsive.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Reece

```
<div id="meettheband">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 nobby">
      <img src="/Users/Reece/Desktop/SLYDE_RESPONSIVE/img/GLAMPLATFORMS.jpg" class="platforms">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 dave">
      <img src="/Users/Reece/Desktop/SLYDE_RESPONSIVE/img/GLAMPLATFORMS.jpg" class="platforms">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 jammy">
      <img src="/Users/Reece/Desktop/SLYDE_RESPONSIVE/img/GLAMPLATFORMS.jpg" class="platforms">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 dozy">
      <img src="/Users/Reece/Desktop/SLYDE_RESPONSIVE/img/GLAMPLATFORMS.jpg" class="platforms">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

#meettheband {

   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.nobby {
  border: red solid;
}

.dave {
  border: red  solid;
}

.jammy {
  border: red  solid;
}

.dozy {
  border: red  solid;
}

img .platforms {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
}
```

Comment: you should set your images wit css and background-size: cover;

Comment: bootstrap ? on your imgs you need to use the class `img-responsive`

Comment: great!! thanks Dani. I don't suppose you know how to make them so they are not spilling over the edges of the site do you? Thanks so much!!

Comment: img width:100%, perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Valius79. Thanks though :/

Comment: If you want, give us a link so we can troubleshoot and try to help you out.

Comment: Great. Here you go: http://pastebin.com/pKeZSRfD

Comment: Any luck @Valius79?

Comment: I can't see your images. What is the pixel size of those 4 images? Or can you link those absolutely so we can see them?

Comment: they are 600 x 600 @Valius69